# Mongoose Geolocation set default coordinates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation

I am trying to create mongoose geolocation records with default coordinates.  I am able to set the default values so it they are serialized, but they are not really committed to the database so geospatial queries won't work.  Here is what I am doing (simplified)

```
const Place = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'], 
      required: true,
      default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true,
      default: function () {
        return [0, 0] // Just 0, 0 for the example
      }
    }
  }
```

When I pull up the record in the mongo shell, there is no `location` key at all.

Comment: if you want use geolocation in your project you can use `Redis` it's wonderful

Answer (score 0):

i don't know more efficient way
but try this :

```
//pass data like this in your controller

    Store.create({name, lat, lon})
```

make your model like this

```
const Place = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  lat: { type: String},
  lon: { type: String},
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'], 
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      index: '2dsphere'
    }
  }

// run before saving documents 
Place.pre('save', function(next) {
       this.location = {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [this.lat, this.lon]
        }; 
            
   next();
});
```